# Are Generic Generic type parameters in C# allowed in some form

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I would like to create the following class snippet

```
class Lookup<TKey,TValue,TCollection>
where TCollection : ICollection<>
{
    public TCollection<TKey> _KeyCollection;
    public TCollection<TValue> _ValueCollection;
}
```

Is this pattern in general possible in C#? In the current form the compiler does not like it. You can't seem to constrain a type parameter to be a generic. However it looks like it a reasonable thing to want to do. Is there any trick to achieve it?

**Note**: This question is specifically about generics and type constraints. It is not looking for a work around for what you think I might be trying to do in my wider application.

Comment: No chance that would work. You would be constraining TCollection to be two different non generic types. I tried it anyway in case you ask ;)

Comment: can you provide sample how you want use it?

Comment: Why would you like to have TCollection to be be generic? Is it not sufficient to have two ICollections as fields?

Comment: The example is above. I want to expose two public fields. They both must derive from ``ICollection<>``

Comment: @bradgonesurfing i mean how you want use class Lookup, more precisely how you want create instance?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I'm not looking for a work around. I have that allready in my code. I'm just curious to see if the above specific pattern is possible in C#

Comment: You can't constrain a generic to be an *open* generic type, which seems to be how you're attempting to use it in the rest of the class.

Comment: That is probably the answer I'm looking for. If you want to provide that as an answer I'll accept it unless some wizard comes up with a good trick. Referring to the correct part in the standard will get bonus points :)

Comment: @bradgonesurfing you can look in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) about constraints, you can use `Interface name` or `Base class name` but you need specify generic parameters because name contains it

Comment: @bradgonesurfing, the _wizard of C# and Java_ was around here minutes ago. I guess he arrived at his office...

Comment: @AndreiV yep, you right :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't constrain a generic type parameter to be an *open* generic type, which seems to be how you're attempting to use it in the rest of the class.

You asked for a spec reference, and there's not one place that seems to spell it out in a nice, concise manner.

The best I can find is in section 4.5 (from C# 5.0 spec):

> As a type, type parameters are purely a compile-time construct. At run-time, each type parameter is bound to a run-time type that was specified by supplying a type argument to the generic type declaration. Thus, the type of a variable declared with a type parameter will, at run-time, be a closed constructed type (§4.4.2). The run-time execution of all statements and expressions involving type parameters uses the actual type that was supplied as the type argument for that parameter.

But in your attempt, `TCollection` won't match up with this text because it's asking for an non-closed type.

Comment: Perhaps also useful, from 4.4.3: "The only construct in which an unbound generic type can be referenced is the `typeof` expression (§7.6.11)."

Answer (score 3):

You can't have an open generic type as a constraint.  You can, however, have a closed generic type:

```
class Lookup<TKey, TValue, TKeyCollection, TValueCollection>
    where TKeyCollection : ICollection<TKey>
    where TValueCollection : ICollection<TValue>
{
    public TKeyCollection _KeyCollection;
    public TValueCollection _ValueCollection;
}
```

It may not be pretty and there are a lot of type parameters, but it is possible.

Comment: Well actually that is the work around in my real code except that it is ``too`` generic. TKeyCollection and TValueCollection can inherit from different bases. One could be List<TKey> and the other could be HashSet<TValue> which is a little too broad.

Comment: Theoretically you could shrink it down a bit more by adding another type parameter to constrain the base of `TKeyCollection` and `TValueCollection`.  You just have to use the non-generic interface (ex. `IList` or `ICollection`).  You won't be able to nail down the exact type though.